# Hibernate @Version and DTO's

Tags: hibernate, version, dto

Design question for Hibernate usage with DTO's.

On one of our entities we use optimistic locking and the @Version annotation.  The current problem is that on merge that version number is not updated until post flush.  This means that it happens outside of our DTO conversion process.  We end up sending the converted DTO back to the client with the old version number.  Subsequent operations on this would now cause optimistic lock failures as Hibernate checks the db version number which is different.

I have managed to fix this with a few hacks that involved using ThreadLocal containers and event listeners but wonder if there is an accepted best practice around how you handle properties that are updated by the system post flush when you use business / client DTO's.

Any ideas or thoughts appreciated,
Thanks,
Shands

Comment: Can't you simply call flush() before transforming the entities to DTOs?

Comment: Apologies should explain - trying to do this within a standard DAO framework hence I would like to try and avoid early flushing if possible as we would probably need to apply to all merge operations. That behaviour may not be desirable across our system.

Answer (score 0):

If the entity will be updated concurrently by many clients. it really needs keep up-to-date version in your client view. you need to refresh it when you make changes (reload it after updating it).

If the entity will be updated only by its owner (not concurrently multiple users ). you don't need keep  newest version property. When you do updation on server side. you can load the stored entity and set proproerties which need to be updated with your DTO, and the loaded PO can be updated automatically within transaction.